# How do I write a "tab" in Python?

Tags: python, tabs

Let's say I have a file. How do I write "hello" TAB "alex"?

Comment: tab implies '\t'

Comment: The title for this question is vague.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

This is the code:

```
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write("hello\talex")
```

The `\t` inside the string is the escape sequence for the horizontal tabulation.

Comment: Using `print "a\tb"` gives me `a       (8 spaces)b` in the `cmd` on `Windows`. Why is it printing 8 spaces instead of the tab character.

Comment: What else were you expecting?

Comment: To display `a (tab character)b`

Comment: @IulianOnofrei A tab character is a non-printing character, also known as whitespace. You don't see anything when press the Tab key. It just moves the text over by a default number of spaces. Maybe you can draw in characters what you want to appear. Is it -->  ?

Comment: @RickHenderson That's not true, a tab character is not just a number of spaces. Maybe your Editor is configured to insert spaces on pressing tab. " " is a tab " " is a space. You may not see the difference here, but open up Word/Libre and you will see the difference.

Comment: @Sativa I'm well aware of that thanks. A more correct statement would be the tab moves the text over by a set distance.

Comment: @RickHenderson that isn't true either. A tab should put the next character at the next tab stop, whose distance is variable based on the tab spacing and how long the preceding string is.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei that might be an implementation issue in cmd itself. Monospace consoles may handle text display differently than a text editor would, and auto-convert tabs into spaces on screen.

Answer (score 45):

The Python [reference manual](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) includes several string literals that can be used in a string. These special sequences of characters are replaced by the intended meaning of the escape sequence.

Here is a table of some of the more useful escape sequences and a description of the output from them.

```
Escape Sequence       Meaning
\t                    Tab
\\                    Inserts a back slash (\)
\'                    Inserts a single quote (')
\"                    Inserts a double quote (")
\n                    Inserts a ASCII Linefeed (a new line)
```

**Basic Example**

If i wanted to print some data points separated by a tab space I could print this string.

```
DataString = "0\t12\t24"
print (DataString)
```

Returns

```
0    12    24
```

**Example for Lists**

Here is another example where we are printing the items of list and we want to sperate the items by a TAB.

```
DataPoints = [0,12,24]
print (str(DataPoints[0]) + "\t" + str(DataPoints[1]) + "\t" + str(DataPoints[2]))
```

Returns

```
0    12    24
```

**Raw Strings**

Note that raw strings (a string which include a prefix "r"), string literals will be ignored. This allows these special sequences of characters to be included in strings without being changed.

```
DataString = r"0\t12\t24"
print (DataString)
```

Returns

```
0\t12\t24
```

Which maybe an undesired output

**String Lengths**

It should also be noted that string literals are only one character in length.

```
DataString = "0\t12\t24"
print (len(DataString))
```

Returns

```
7
```

The raw string has a length of 9.

Comment: I need to have a space between my elements that is around half of `\t`. How can I do this?

Comment: The Example for Lists is an eyesore. `"\t".join(map(str, DataPoints))` or `print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(*DataPoints))` are significantly DRYer.

Answer (score 28):

You can use \t in a string literal:

`"hello\talex"`

Answer (score 15):

It's usually `\t` in command-line interfaces, which will convert the char `\t` into the whitespace tab character.

For example, `hello\talex` -> `hello--->alex`.

Answer (score 15):

As it wasn't mentioned in any answers, just in case you want to align and space your text, you can use the string format features. (above python 2.5) Of course `\t` is actually a TAB token whereas the described method generates spaces.

**Example:**

```
print "{0:30} {1}".format("hi", "yes")
> hi                             yes
```

**Another Example, left aligned:**

```
print("{0:<10} {1:<10} {2:<10}".format(1.0, 2.2, 4.4))
>1.0        2.2        4.4
```

Comment: how to give tab character to print 3 dimensional array element as 0    12    24 as 3 rows?

Comment: Added to the answer

Answer (score 4):

Here are some more exotic Python 3 ways to get "hello" TAB "alex" (tested with Python 3.6.10):

`"hello\N{TAB}alex"`

`"hello\N{tab}alex"`

`"hello\N{TaB}alex"`

`"hello\N{HT}alex"`

`"hello\N{CHARACTER TABULATION}alex"`

`"hello\N{HORIZONTAL TABULATION}alex"`

`"hello\x09alex"`

`"hello\u0009alex"`

`"hello\U00000009alex"`

Actually, instead of using an escape sequence, it is possible to insert tab symbol directly into the string literal. Here is the code with a tabulation character to copy and try:

`"hello alex"`

If the tab in the string above won't be lost anywhere during copying the string then "print(repr(< string from above >)" should print 'hello\talex'.

See [respective Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Assume I have a variable named `file` that contains a file.
Then I could use `file.write("hello\talex")`.

1. `file.write("hello` means I'm starting to write to this file.
2. `\t` means a tab
3. `alex")` is the rest I'm writing

Comment: Should this not be \t  as you mention in step 2?

Comment: @User1010 \t _does_ mean a tab. I am using [escape characters](https://www.python-ds.com/python-3-escape-sequences)

Comment: I am familiar with escape chars however you have written hello/t not hello\t

Comment: @User1010  I made the accident on the `file.write("hello\talex")`. Now I fixed it.