# how to indent all the columns in a file using python

Tags: python, parsing, indentation

I wanted to align all the strings in each column of a file in a particular order using a python script.  I have described the problem and the possible outcome using a sample scenario.

```
#sample.txt

start() "hello"
appended() "fly"
instantiated() "destination"
do() "increment"
logging_sampler() "dummy string"
```

Output scenario

```
#sample.txt(indented)

start()           "hello"
appended()        "fly"
instantiated()    "destination"
do()              "increment"
logging_sampler() "dummy string"
```

So is there any python library that can process a file and provide the above indentation? 
Is there any general solution such that if I have a file with more that 2 columns and I can still indent all the columns in the same manner?

Answer (score 4):

So is there any python library that can process a file and provide the above indentation? **NO**

Is this Possible? **Yes**

You need to know a way to `parse your line`s and then `display in a formatted manner`

In your particular case, `parsing` is straight forward as you just need to split the string based on the first occurring space. This can easily be done using [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition). At times you may even need some exotic parsing logic for which you may need to use [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

`Formatting` is even simpler, if you know the [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

**Demo**

```
>>> for e in st.splitlines():
    left,_,right = e.partition(' ')
    print "{:<20}{:<20}".format(left, right)


start()             "hello"             
appended()          "fly"               
instantiated()      "destination"       
do()                "increment"         
logging_sampler()   "dummy string"
```

Comment: the above code works for the given scenarios. But is there any general solution such that if I have a file with more that 2 columns and i still need to indent all the columns in the same manner?

Comment: @karthik: Unfortunately, there is no psychic library for this purpose.

Comment: @karthik: You can iterate through the left side items and find out which of them is longest by using [`len()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len). You can then use [`str.ljust()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to apply the wanted padding by using the value of the maximum found length and adding some value, say, 1, to it.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13214945/989121) here's a function takes a list of string lists, and returns a list formatted lines.

```
def table(lines, delim='\t'):
    lens = [len(max(col, key=len)) for col in zip(*lines)]
    fmt = delim.join('{:' + str(x) + '}' for x in lens)
    return [fmt.format(*line) for line in lines]
```

The rest is trivial:

```
import re
with open(__file__) as fp:
    lines = [re.split(r' ', s.strip(), maxsplit=1) for s in fp]
print '\n'.join(table(lines))
```

http://ideone.com/9WucPj

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tab character ("\t") in your printing, but I'm not clear how you are printing sample.txt.

```
print string1+"\t"+string2
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488570/how-do-i-write-a-tab-in-python) for more details